# Toad for Oracle - Any good tutorial for beginners?

Tags: oracle10g, toad

I just start working on oracle and using **Toad for Oracle** but it is not as simple to use any good,simple and easy reference material/manual/tutorial or how to use **Toad for oracle** efficiently? Particularly I am using **Toad for Oracle 10.6**

Kind Note: If you feel question is not constructive then you can please ignore it because such questions really matters for beginners.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ToadForOracle.com redirects to ToadWorld here:
http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/default.aspx
The getting-started videos provide orientation.
The user guide (this one specific to v11.6) is here:
http://documents.quest.com/Toad%20for%20Oracle/11.6.1/User%20Guide/
to view online, or download the pdf in the top-right corner.
Regards,
Donna
TfO tech-writer